# Whenever Gem: whenever command is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

On my development VM and on the server, running whenever command `$ bundle exec whenever` is not working. I get back the following:

```
$ bundle exec whenever
bundler: failed to load command: whenever (/home/cgarndt/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/whenever)
config/schedule.rb:35:in `initialize': uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Whenever::JobList:0x0000555d07619838>>::Rails (NameError)
    from /home/cgarndt/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/whenever-1.0.0/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `instance_eval'
    ... ... ...
```

On my development machine I am running:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- rbenv
- Ruby 3.0
- Rails 7.0.4
- whenever (1.0.0)

I have ran `$ bundle exec wheneverize .` which ran successfully and created schedule.rb file.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you
Chris

**Update**. My schedule.rb file:

```
# Need the below for Cron to pick up rbenv user version within Unix-user/application.
# Vs w/o the below line then Cron uses rbenv system version.
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

# Compare Person API CALS People data to CALS-2 People data
if Rails.env.staging?
  every :monday, at: '7:50am' do
    runner "CjComparePersApiCalsPeople::Start.execute"
  end
end
if ::Rails.env.production?
  every :monday, at: '8:05am' do
    runner "CjComparePersApiCalsPeople::Start.execute"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show your schedule.rb file, since this is where the error is actually occurring. Chances are you are calling `Rails` and you need to change this to `::Rails`

Comment: @engineersmnky if you make your comment into an answer I will happily give you credit. What lead you to the answer that I was calling Rails (which was the issue)? I will post my schedule.rb file in the state that was giving the error. I was trying to having different times set, one for staging and another on production.

Comment: `#<Class:#<Whenever::JobList:0x0000555d07619838>>::Rails` is what lead me to that suggestion. This is a constant lookup issue so instead we are referring to `Rails` as a TOP_LEVEL constant (`::Rails`) which will resolve the lookup concerns as long as `Rails` is loaded.